# Highlight highest value in rows using proc tabulate

Tags: sas, crosstab

I need help. how can i highlight the highest value in each row, like in this example

```
51.30 - 50.50  - 57.50 - 85.00  - 54.40 - 67.75
58.05 - 80.75  - 60.37 - 103.50 - 59.44 - 94.40
60.90 - 91.00  - 62.50 - 84.00  - 61.43 - 88.67 
63.55 - 96.25  - 66.25 - 107.50 - 64.90 - 101.88 
64.50 - 112.25 - 66.75 - 122.50 - 65.63 - 117.38 
.     -   .    - 72.00 - 150.00 - 72.00 - 150.00
```

i need to highlight **85.00**, **103.50**, **91.00**, **107.50** .... and so on, with a different color excluding the total of course

here's the code for that example:

```
ods html file='D:/test.html';

proc tabulate data=sashelp.class f=7.2 style={background=yellow};
    var height/style={background=green foreground=white};
    var weight/style={background=blue foreground=white};

    class age/style={background=pink foreground=purple};
    classlev age/style={background=purple foreground=pink};

    class sex/style={background=white foreground=black};
    classlev sex/style={background=red foreground=white};

table
       age all,
       mean=' '*sex='Gender Avg'*(height*{s={font_size=8pt}} weight) 
       mean='Overall Avg'*(height weight*{s={font_size=14pt}}) / 
       box={label='Box Label' s={background=bib foreground=cyan}}; 

       ;
    run;

ods html close;
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't have time for a complete answer, but in general, I think you will have to use `PROC REPORT` for this; it may take a transpose and some flexibility on format as well as I'm not sure you can do this easily with `ACROSS` variables.

Answer (score 0):

SAS Support provides an adequate solution:

**Maximum Value**

- The below example traffic lights based on the maximum value of the
  observation.
- The PROC SQL code puts the maximum value into a series of macro
  variables.
- PROC FORMAT with MACRO builds a format with the maximum value.The
  table template is used to create the style with the BACKGROUND=
  attribute.

This method is a little messy and might not work for you -- if a maximum value from one row appears in any subsequent rows, it will be highlighted there as well. (In this example, there are no maximum values that are repeated later.)

```
  data one;
     input c x y z;
   cards;
   1 7 31 4
   4 9 5 10
   1 73 3 4
   40 9 5 6
   8 70 3 4
   5 2 90 6
   ;
   run;

   proc sql;
     select count(c) into: num
       from one;
     select distinct( max(c,x,y,z)) into : temp1- :temp%left(&num)
       from one;
   run;
   quit;

   %put &temp1 &temp2;

   %macro test;
   proc format ;
     value test (multilabel)
       %do i=1 %to &num;
         &&temp&i="red"
       %end;other="green";
   run;
   %mend;
   %test

   proc template;
     define table test;
       parent=base.datastep.table;
         define column c;
           style={background=test.};
         end;
         define column x;
           style={background=test.};
         end;
         define column y;
           style={background=test.};
         end;
         define column z;
           style={background=test.};
         end;
     end;
   run;

   ods html body='temp.html';
   data _null_;
     set one;
     file print ods=(template='test');
     put _ods_;
   run;

   ods html close;
```